Mouseleave event triggers exception and click event doesn't
I want dropdown list to disappear when mouse leaves #navbarHint div element.


let flag2 = true;

document.getElementById('navbarHint').addEventListener('mouseleave',
  function() {
    flag2 = false;
    menuClick();
  });

document.getElementById('navbtn').addEventListener('click', menuClick);

function menuClick() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content');
  if (flag2) {
    menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
    flag2 = false
  } else {
    menu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    flag2 = true;
  }
}
#navbarHint {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: grey;
}

.dropdown-content {
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  min-width: max-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateX(-3rem) translateY(2.5rem);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content p {
  margin-inline: 0.25rem;
  margin-block: 0.5rem;
}

#navbtn {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbarHint">
    <div id="navbtn" class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



So the list should disappear when I leave certain area on the page. But it doesn't. It raises Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') exception, although it works perfectly when menuClick function is called from click event. For some reason it does matter which event is calling the function.
I also tried this with document.getElementById('navbtn').addEventListener('mouseleave', menuClick); - and it doesn't work as well.

Could you please use the html snippet option (the button on the right side of the insert image button, it has '<>' inside) so we can see your code in action instead of imagining it? Based on the exception it looks like .dropdown:hover .dropdown-contentdoesn't find the element and returns null, probably because :hover isn't working as expected.

I added the snippet. Kind of. Let me fix it a bit

Alright, does it work now?

I dont think you can use .dropdown:hover with querySelector.

@Mehdi There is no problem with :hover inside the querySelector, its that he isn't hovering over that element anymore because navbarHint is bigger. Thatswhy its only working via click because on click he is actually hovering over it.

@Fabian, you are correct but I don t think it generaly makes much sens to use it in querySelector, he can use mouseenter

As I already suspected in the comment this is a conflict between the :hover selector and the area you attached mouseleave to. The leave event fires when wou leave navbarHint but by that time you are no longer hovering over .dropdown so document.querySelector('.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content')returns null resulting in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style').
Try removing :hover or if it's required please explain why.


let flag2 = true;

document.getElementById('navbarHint').addEventListener('mouseleave',
  function() {
    flag2 = false;
    menuClick();
  });

document.getElementById('navbtn').addEventListener('click', menuClick);

function menuClick() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown-content');
  if (flag2) {
    menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
    flag2 = false
  } else {
    menu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    flag2 = true;
  }
}
#navbarHint {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: grey;
}

.dropdown-content {
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  min-width: max-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateX(-3rem) translateY(2.5rem);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content p {
  margin-inline: 0.25rem;
  margin-block: 0.5rem;
}

#navbtn {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbarHint">
    <div id="navbtn" class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Ah, I didn't even notice this little :hover... I removed it in my code and now it works. Thank you.

Replace your js with below. The function menuClick takes an argument - the event - from which you can access the target element you wish to hide:
let flag2 = true;

function init() {
  document.getElementById('navbarHint').addEventListener('mouseleave', 
  (ev) => { 
      flag2 = false;
      menuClick(ev);
  });
  
  document.getElementById('navbtn').addEventListener('click', (ev) => menuClick(ev));
 
}

function menuClick(ev)
{
    const content = ev.target.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown-content');
    console.log(content);
    if (flag2)
    {
        content.style.visibility = 'visible';
        flag2 = false
    }
    else
    {
        content.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        flag2 = true;
    }
}

init();


I think this will hide the entire navbarHint instead of only the dropdown?

@FabianN. I updated the code to show/hide the content element
